How to process this text?
I have a text file that contains these lines and I'm not exactly sure what's the best way to use Python to load into separate key:value pairs.
dummy-test-foo,rsa,4096,[DNS.1:dummy-test,DNS.2:dummy-test-foo2],[IP.1:192.168.10.5,IP.2:192.168.20.5]
dummy-test-jerry,rsa,4096,[DNS.1:dummy-testX,DNS.2:dummy-test-jerry],[IP.1:192.168.40.5,IP.2:192.168.50.5]
dummy-test-tom,rsa,4096,[DNS.1:dummy-testY,DNS.2:dummy-test-tom],[IP.1:192.168.60.5,IP.2:192.168.70.5]

The challenge is the embedded array within each line.
Novice Python programmer, not sure where to start.

Could you please provide the output you expect to get?

Is it possible to change the file format? If you could put quotes around the fields that contain [...], you could use the standard csv module to parse it.

Without a regexp it can be done in the following way:
lines = [
    "dummy-test-foo,rsa,4096,[DNS.1:dummy-test,DNS.2:dummy-test-foo2],[IP.1:192.168.10.5,IP.2:192.168.20.5]",
    "dummy-test-jerry,rsa,4096,[DNS.1:dummy-testX,DNS.2:dummy-test-jerry],[IP.1:192.168.40.5,IP.2:192.168.50.5]",
    "dummy-test-tom,rsa,4096,[DNS.1:dummy-testY,DNS.2:dummy-test-tom],[IP.1:192.168.60.5,IP.2:192.168.70.5]",
]

def parse_line(line: str) -> dict:
    result: dict = {}

    # Split by comma
    line = line.split(",")

    # Find all words containing colon
    for word in line:
        if ":" not in word:
            continue

        # Remove brackets and convert to key / value pair
        word = "".join(char for char in word if char not in "[]")
        key, value = word.split(":")

        result[key] = value

    return result

for line_ in lines:
    parse_line(line=line_)


Thank you everyone for helping me with this! Very grateful for all the code snippet, I ended up using the snippet from @VictorEgiazarian and was able to parse the input file and load it into a dictionary of key:value pairs.

They did standardize the input a little more to make sure all the values before the square brackets were semi-colon separated name:values also. Works perfectly!

There is the flow for accepting the answer. If the answer really helped you, could you mark it with a check mark)

Use the str.split() function with the maxsplit option to limit it to the first 3 commas. Then you can use a regular expression to extract the arrays from the rest.
import re

array_rx = re.compile(r'\[(.*?)\]')

with open("testarrays.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        name, type, size, arrays = line.split(',', maxsplit=3)
        # split the arrays string into separate elements, removing [] delimiters
        arrays = array_rx.findall(arrays)
        print(name, type, size, arrays)

